# How to automate Java EAR code setup process in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, automation, myeclipse

I would like to automate steps for Java development Code setup in My-eclipse. Below are steps which needs to be automated.

1) Check out list of Projects (Complete list or PSF file can be provided) from specified SVN location.
2) Run a mentioned list of source generation from external tools configuration
3) Clean and build complete workspace
4) Start server in debugging mode
5) Deploy specified project to the server.

Can any help in identifying scripting language or tool which can be used to automate above steps ?

Comment: If this is a development set up, I'm not sure why you'd want to start the server and deploy the project automatically; isn't this what a developer would do multiple times during development? With the automatic build option selected, then importing projects from SVN would get them built automatically. Not sure about source generation tools.

Comment: I would like automate initial setup for local development setup. Normally all steps I mentioned takes around 4-5 hrs, so automating it would help us in saving that time. I want to create a tool which would do these steps in sequence automatically once triggered.

Comment: Maybe maven could do the generation step as part of the build but I'm not aware of anything in eclipse that could do what you want. Hopefully, others can give some suggestions.